# Signig data string with private key (.pem file) in C# .net core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, rsa, pkcs#1

The following code in python is my baseline that I need to implement using .net core

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
import base64


thing_to_sign = "12345"
key = RSA.importKey(open('dev.private.pem').read())
signer = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)
data = SHA256.new(thing_to_sign)
signedData = signer.sign(data)
sig =  base64.b64encode(signedData)

print sig
```

for now i have tried to do the same with BouncyCastel but got a different result than i should.

```
var data = "12345";
var keyParams = ReadAsymmetricKeyParameter("dev.private.pem");
var encryptEngine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());
encryptEngine.Init(true, keyParams);
var dataBytes = GetSHA256Bytes(data);
var signedData = encryptEngine.ProcessBlock(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
var sig64 = Convert.ToBase64String(signedData);

const string expectedSig = "MEka+7qTARRoXWmU4nm6sBc9R8908AIx.... shorten for reading convinience";
Assert.Equal(expectedSig, sig64); //Fails here the result is differnt the python code :(
```

the `ReadAsymmetricKeyParameter` method:

```
private AsymmetricKeyParameter ReadAsymmetricKeyParameter(string pemFilename)
{
    var fileStream = File.OpenText(pemFilename);
    var pemReader = new PemReader(fileStream);
    var keyParameter = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair) pemReader.ReadObject();
    return keyParameter.Private;
}
```

Then i figured that the `Pkcs1Encoding` might not be 1.5 as it should and could not find enougth infor about it so im trying to revert to use `System.Security.Cryptography` from the .Net Framework but stuck at how to load the private pem key file

```
var dataStr = "12345";
using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
    var data = GetSHA256Bytes(dataStr);
    var rsaFormatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(rsa);
    rsaFormatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA256");
    byte[] SignedHash = rsaFormatter.CreateSignature(data);
    var sig64 = Convert.ToBase64String(SignedHash);
}
```

The `GetSHA256Bytes` helper is straightforward:

```
        using (var hash = SHA256.Create())
        {
            return hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
        }
```

Comment: See my response at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46722997/saml-assertion-in-a-xml-using-c-sharp/46724392

Comment: @jdweng thanks in your method `SignXmlWithCertificate` your using a `X509Certificate2 ` to get the private key .. but i dot have pfx i have only a private.dev.pem and public.dev.pem files can i generate a pfx from them somehow  ?

Comment: See msdn : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d7e2ccea-4bea-4f22-890b-7e48c267657f/creating-a-x509-certificate-from-a-rsa-private-key-in-pem-file?forum=csharpgeneral and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @jdweng Thanks you so much !! that was exactlly what i needed .. i wonder why its not an exsisting nuget or something .. 
can you post it as an answer ?

Comment: Why use thrid party nuget app code when you can use straight code from the Net Library?