# How to declared namespace prefix in SOAP header

Tags: c#, soap, header, namespaces

I'm using following code to add header to soap header.

```
using (new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(
        MessageHeader.CreateHeader("ns:To", "", "http://###.com"));                                
}
```

But I got `undeclared namespace prefix ns` error, I will need add `xmlns:ns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"` to name space.

So my question is how to add namespace prefix to

```
<s:Envelope>
    <s:Header>
        <ns:To>##</ns:To>
    </s:Header>
</s:Envelope>
```

To

```
<s:Envelope>
    <s:Header xmlns:ns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <ns:To>##</ns:To>
    </s:Header>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: May be this will help you ... https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/05a561cd-879b-4dc7-ac1a-88a879272400/how-to-add-attribute-to-wcf-message-header-with-messageheadercreateheader-method?forum=wcf

Comment: See my solution at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46722997/saml-assertion-in-a-xml-using-c-sharp/46724392#comment80642919_46724392

Comment: @m.kudi thank you for the reply, put in my code, but not add namespace to header.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String oasisWsSecNS = "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing";
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
     
XmlElement child = document.CreateElement("To", oasisWsSecNS);
child.AppendChild(document.CreateTextNode("[value]"));
element.AppendChild(child);
            
context.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Header", oasisWsSecNS, document.DocumentElement));
```