# sslStream.AuthenticateAsClientAsync does not accepts client certificate

Tags: c#, ssl, sslstream

I am trying to use `SslStream` to establish `TLS` connection to server.
When I don't provide the certificate, everything is working as expected.

However when I try to use self signed client certificate with same server, it does not works.

- When I use `cer` file (certificate without private key), the certificate is not sent (certificate tls packet has certificate length `0`).
- When I try to use pfx file that contains certificate, private key and `ca` certificate, I receive the error

> "The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized"

I have tried to install both `pfx` and server certificate on Windows, however it did not help.

Exception stack trace is:

> at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
>   lazyResult)
>   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult
>   iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean
>   requiresSynchronization)

I have tried to load the `pfx` by using:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(path, password);
```

And

```
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection collection = 
    new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection();

collection.Import(path, password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
```

Both lead to same errors.
- CheckCertificateRevocation is set to false.
- Enabled protocols are set to `Tls | Tls11 | Tls12`
- Target host is set to dns name of remote server.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46722997/saml-assertion-in-a-xml-using-c-sharp/46724392  Codeproject is another goo source.  There are many c# ssl project at codeprojects. See this one as a sample : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1000189/A-Working-TCP-Client-and-Server-With-SSL