# Add security header to a SOAP message

Tags: c#, soap-client, ws-security

I'm not really proficient in soap calls.
I should make the following soap call.
I suffered with it for several days, but it doesn't work.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:v1="http://eeszt.gov.hu/ns/helloworld/ws/HelloWorldService/v1">
<soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasisopen.org/wss/2004/01/oasis- 200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
     xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurityutility-1.0.xsd">
     <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-B05DFFAAB2CD6C6C9E14363584263357">
     <wsu:Created>2015-07-08T12:27:06.335Z</wsu:Created>
     <wsu:Expires>2015-07-08T12:32:06.335Z</wsu:Expires>
     </wsu:Timestamp>
      <saml:Assertion ID="id-" ...</saml:Assertion>
   </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
  <v1:helloWorldRequest>
  ...
  </v1:helloWorldRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope
```

That's what I tried

1. Create custom binding and webservice

```
CustomBinding wsBinding = new CustomBinding();
string baseAddress = "https://dev-if.eeszt.gov.hu:443/TOR";
EndpointAddress wsEndPointAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(baseAddress));
wsBinding = CreateBindingForTp();
TorWSClient twsClient = new TorWSClient(wsBinding, wsEndPointAddress);

X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509Certificate2(@eesztCert.certFileName, @eesztCert.certPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
byte[] rawData = ReadFile(@eesztCert.certFileName);
x509.Import(rawData, @eesztCert.certPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
twsClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = x509;

twsClient.Open();
```

2. Add security header and call webservice

```
 SoapSecurityHeader soapSecurityHeader = new SoapSecurityHeader(Saml.samlTicket);
 using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel)twsClient.InnerChannel))
   {
      OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(soapSecurityHeader);
   }

try
 {
   gtrspt = twsClient.getTorzs(gtrt);
 }
catch (Exception ex)
 {
    MessageBoxEx.Show(ex.Message, "Error !", MessageBoxButtons.OK, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Information);
 }
```

3. Create security header

```
 public class SoapSecurityHeader : MessageHeader
    {
        private readonly string  _samlticket;
        private readonly DateTime _createdDate;

        public SoapSecurityHeader(string samlTicket)
        {
            _samlticket = samlTicket;
            _createdDate = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public string Id { get; set; }


        public override string Name
        {
            get { return "Security "; }
        }

        public override string Namespace
        {
            get { return "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"; }
        }

        protected override void OnWriteStartHeader(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("wsse", Name, Namespace);
            writer.WriteXmlnsAttribute("wsu", "wsu http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");
        }

        protected override void OnWriteHeaderContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("wsu", "Timestamp", null);
            writer.WriteAttributeString("wsu", "Id", null, "TimeId1");
            writer.WriteElementString("wsu", "Created", null, _createdDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'"));
            writer.WriteElementString("wsu", "Expires", null, _createdDate.AddSeconds(300).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'"));

            writer.WriteEndElement();

            string sml = Saml.samlTicket;
            writer.WriteRaw("<saml:Assertion ID=" + @"""");
            writer.WriteRaw(sml + @"""");
            writer.WriteRaw("</saml:Assertion>");

        }
    }
}
```

4. Binding

```
public CustomBinding CreateBindingForTp()
        {

            CustomBinding customBinding = new CustomBinding();
            TransportSecurityBindingElement security = new TransportSecurityBindingElement()
            {
                IncludeTimestamp = true,
                MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10
            };

            TextMessageEncodingBindingElement encoding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8);
            HttpsTransportBindingElement transport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement() { TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered, RequireClientCertificate = true, MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue };

            customBinding.Elements.Clear();
            customBinding.Elements.Add(security);
            customBinding.Elements.Add(encoding);
            customBinding.Elements.Add(transport);

            return customBinding;
        }
```

I generated the proxy class from wsdl. Only one wsse header should be added.
The wsse header is not included in the webservice call.

I want a simpler solution.
Sorry for my bad English.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: See my solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46722997/saml-assertion-in-a-xml-using-c-sharp/46724392

Comment: I think your English is great. Perhaps using a few punctuation marks between the "solution Sorry" and "English Thanks" statements would have improved it. But the written words were great.  For example, I would have adjusted it to read:  "I want a simpler solution. Sorry for my bad English. Thanks for the help.".  Use the '.' character like the ';' in 'c'-based language syntax.  :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I corrected.