# Add Saml Assertion to a custom binding

Tags: c#, soap, request-headers

I have this CustomBinding:

```
            var sec = new AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement(
            new X509SecurityTokenParameters(X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.Any, SecurityTokenInclusionMode.Never),
            new X509SecurityTokenParameters(X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.Any, SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToRecipient));
            sec.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10;
            sec.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Strict;
            sec.IncludeTimestamp = true;
            sec.SetKeyDerivation(false);
            sec.KeyEntropyMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityKeyEntropyMode.ServerEntropy;
            sec.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;

            CustomBinding myBinding = new CustomBinding();
            myBinding.Elements.Add(sec);

            myBinding.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8));
            myBinding.Elements.Add(new HttpsTransportBindingElement());
```

I would like to add some SAML assertions like this:

```
        <saml:Assertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" saml:ID="authorization-assertion" saml:IssueInstant="2020-11-12T09:10:27Z" saml:Version="2.0" wsu:Id="authorization-assertion" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion saml-schema-assertion-2.0.xsd">
        <saml:Issuer>COMPANY</saml:Issuer>
        <saml:Subject>
            <saml:nameID>02942630753.localhost.com</saml:nameID>
        </saml:Subject>
        <saml:AuthzDecisionStatement Decision="Permit" Resource="IDocument">
            <saml:Action Namespace="http://FSE/IDocumentService"/>
        </saml:AuthzDecisionStatement>
        <saml:AttributeStatement/>
    </saml:Assertion>
```

I thought I might use: myBinding.Elements.Add(), But I don't know how to construct the Assertion element.

Answer (score 0):

As I said yesterday on your previous posting to read a template from a file.  You can also put it in code like code below using xml linq.  If you read from a file replace the Parse() method with Load() method. :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string assertion = 
                "<saml:Assertion xmlns:saml=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion\"" + 
                    " xmlns:wsu=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\"" + 
                    " xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"" + 
                    " saml:ID=\"authorization-assertion\"" +
                    " saml:IssueInstant=\"2020-11-12T09:10:27Z\"" +
                    " saml:Version=\"2.0\"" +
                    " wsu:Id=\"authorization-assertion\"" + 
                    " xsi:schemaLocation=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion saml-schema-assertion-2.0.xsd\">" +
  
                    "<saml:Issuer>COMPANY</saml:Issuer>" +
                    "<saml:Subject>" +
                        "<saml:nameID>02942630753.localhost.com</saml:nameID>" +
                    "</saml:Subject>" +
                    "<saml:AuthzDecisionStatement Decision=\"Permit\" Resource=\"IDocument\">" +
                        "<saml:Action Namespace=\"http://FSE/IDocumentService\"/>" +
                    "</saml:AuthzDecisionStatement>" +
                    "<saml:AttributeStatement/>" +
                "</saml:Assertion>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(assertion);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but it doesn't solve my problem, which is a bit different from the previous one anyway. I try to be clearer:
I want to add an Assertion in my binding using c # code and not import an xml file and create an XDocument. They are two completely different things. I believe I can do this using myBinding.Elements.Add (), but I don't know if it's correct and what kind of element to insert.

Comment: You want to create and add custom properties to an xml file.  There is no binding to a string.  You have to create a object to bind (not a string).  So you need either a XmlDocument or a XDocument (xml linq).  See my example from 3 years ago : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46722997/saml-assertion-in-a-xml-using-c-sharp/46724392

Comment: Thanks, but you don't want to use an Xml file, but a method of the CustomBinding class, Elements.Add (), to insert an Assertion. If Elements.Add () is not the correct method, the request is an alternate method, but always as a class of CustomBinding (). Your answer is helpful to my previous question, not this one.

Comment: Try following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=net-5.0

Comment: Sorry for my wrong answer, but I was confused by the line: const string FILENAME = @ "c: \ temp \ test.xml"; never used.
Now I have this situation:
1 - The Assertions created with your help.
2 - My Header with mandatory Security.
3 - The Body created with the WSDL class.
How do I merge all of this and eventually send it as a Soap Request?

Comment: Once you have an XDocument you can modify (add) as required.  Not sure from your posting which values need to be modified.  Eventually you can use doc.ToString() to get a string which you can add to your request.